# Выделение интерфикса

Tags: морфемика

Выделяется ли интерфикс каким-нибудь знаком в разбираемом по составу слове?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что говорится в книге **Русский язык: краткий теоретический курс для школьников. Е. И. Литневская.**

У ученых-лингвистов нет единого мнения по этому вопросу; интерфиксы разных групп принято квалифицировать по-разному.

Соединительные гласные на стыке корней (группа 1) не присоединяются ни к одному, ни к другому корню и остаются между морфемами; при морфемном членении слова их можно выделять скобками, подчеркиванием или обведением соединительного элемента кружком: сам(о)лет-Æ ¬ сам + летать.

Что же касается интерфиксов второй группы, используемых в словообразовании, существует три точки зрения:

1) оставлять их между морфемами (пе(в)ец),

2) присоединять их к корню (пев-ец),

3) присоединять их к суффиксу (пе-вец).

Каждая из этих точек зрения имеет аргументы «за» и «против». Принятому нами алгоритму морфемного разбора соответствует третья точка зрения: суффиксом является тот отрезок производной основы, который отличает ее от основы производящей, например, пе-вец ¬ петь.

Интерфиксы, используемые в словоизменении существительных, принято считать наращениями корня (мать — матер-и), а гласные в конце глагольной основы обозначать как суффиксы (чит-а-ть).