# Как отмечается интерфикс при морфемном разборе?

Tags: морфемный-разбор, гласные

Как, когда схема 2-го разбора по русскому делается, изображается интерфикс, то бишь соединительная гласная?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что написано? Не разберу.

Comment: *Мухомор* и *тамошний*.

Comment: Леопольд-мэтр Что вы имеете в виду под первым вопросом? Вас интересовал вопрос, есть ли соединительная гласная в слове тамошний?

Comment: Как обозначать соединительную гласную на схеме.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433761/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0

Comment: @Серж каллиграфия она такая, да.

Comment: @Буротино, первую запись ещё как-то можно прочитать. Но вторую...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

• Есть рекомендация подчеркивать соединительную гласную:

одной чертой (*спиши, выдели корни, [**подчеркни**](https://nsportal.ru/nachalnaya-shkola/russkii-yazyk/2018/01/15/urok-russkogo-yazyka-v-3-klasse-soedinitelnye-glasnye-o-e) соединительную гласную*);
[двумя](https://znanio.ru/media/soedinitelnye-glasnye-o-e-v-slozhnyh-slovah-2758514) черточками (тогда впереди стоящие согласные тоже отмечаются).

• Есть другой способ: оформление с помощью [скобок](https://urok.1sept.ru/articles/570934) — мух(о)мор.
[Перед соединительной гласной под твёрдой согласной ставят синюю точку, под мягкой согласной — зелёную.]

• Есть даже такое решение:
злословить — "Это сложное слово, состоит из двух корней, поэтому в нем есть соединительная гласная "о". При разборе мы ее [не обозначаем](https://tetrika-school.ru/blog/morfemnyi-razbor/)".

Получается, что фундаментального правила нет.
Значит — надо обозначать так, как принято в учебном заведении.
Ведь главное — правильно написать (**о**, **е** или **и**) и нужное отметить.

**Дополнение**

В прилагательном ***та́мошний*** суффикс *-ошн-* выделен правильно, а гласная "о" подчеркнута, вероятно, потому, что ее нужно **запомнить** (т. к. суффикс *-ашн-* тоже существует; и частенько пишут "тамашний").

> В прилагательных типа *тамошний, теперешний* безударный гласный суффикса перед сочетанием согласных **шн** передается на письме неодинаково. Буква ***о***  пишется в словах *та́мошний, вечо́рошний* (от вечор ‘вчера вечером’), буква ***а***  – в *пра́вдашний, взапра́вдашний* (варианты с твердым **н**: правдашный, взаправдашный); после мягких согласных пишется буква ***е*** в *тепе́решний* и *у́трешний*, ***и***  – в *обе́днишний* (от *обедня*). Под ударением в этом суффиксе – гласный ***и*** в единственном слове *давни́шний*.

[Суффиксы -ошн, -ашн, -ешн, -ишн](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D1%81%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%8B_%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BD_%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD_%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD_%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD/) (Особенности написания отдельных суффиксов, ПАС)

Answer (score 4):

В слове тамошний - ошн - суффикс прилагательного.

Из словаря Ефремовой.

**Суффикс-ошн-(ий)**

Словообразовательная единица, выделяющаяся в именах прилагательных, обозначающих локальный признак, который характеризуется отношением к тому, что названо образующим словом, в роли которого выступают наречия "там" и "тут" (та́мошний, ту́тошний).

Comment: Это, однако, не ответ на 1-й вопрос.

Comment: @Серж Добрый день, Серж!  **Суффикс-ошн-(ий)** — мне вот эта запись не понятна.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова, такова запись в словаре. Видимо имеется в виду, что данный суффикс встречается с окончанием ий.